# Populate a combobox using data from Access database

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have an app with two comboboxes.

When selecting an item in Combobox1, the Combobox3 item will pe populated with data from Access db.

Each selection from Combobox1 has different results in Combobox3.

The code bellow is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

No matter what value I select from Combobox1 I get nothing in Combobox3.

If I change the query to make it wrong it does throw an error.

```
    public void metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.metroTabPage1.Controls.Add(this.metroLabel11);

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\databases\db2010.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            myConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("Select [Equipment] from [Test Equipment] where [Description] = '" + this.metroComboBox1.Text + "';", myConn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = myQuery.ExecuteReader();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);

            foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                string reference = myRow["Equipment"].ToString();
                this.metroComboBox3.Items.AddRange(new object[] { reference });
                //this.metroComboBox3.Items.Add(myRow["Equipment"].ToString());
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ex: " + ex);
        }
        this.metroComboBox3.Items.Add("Other");
        this.metroTabPage1.Controls.Add(this.metroComboBox3);
    }
```

I have tried

```
this.metroComboBox3.Items.Add(myRow["Equip No"].ToString());
```

and

```
string reference = myRow["Equip No"].ToString();
this.metroComboBox3.Items.AddRange(new object[] { reference });
```

with same result.

Comment: Please include tag of language you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is working fine, but there's a few things you have take in mind.

**First:** You have to check if the event `metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` is linked with `metroComboBox1` in designer code.

```
this.metroComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

or add it dynamically

```
metroComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

**Second:** There're a lot of ways to fill the **ComboBox** with data, here's some.

```
this.metroComboBox3.Items.Add(myRow["Equipment"].ToString());
```

or

```
this.metroComboBox3.Items.Add(myRow[0].ToString());
```

or without `foreach` and using **Linq**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
this.metroComboBox3.Items.AddRange(list.Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToArray());
```

**Third:** You have to clear your pervious items in the second **ComboBox**, and this line is done it for you.

```
metroComboBox3.Items.Clear();
```

I hope that question is answered.

Comment: You are correct. The code was good but I used the wrong search parameter for [Description] without realising and was thinking there is something wrong with the code.